# Updating a global variable periodically in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm doing something like pattern matching in spark streaming app. What I want is updating a variable like *broadcast variable*, which however is mutable. Is there a way to do that? Any advice?

**EDIT**

Sorry for not being so clear. I am doing some CEP stuff on logs. I need to load the rules from elasticsearch while the spark application is running. And I wanna apply these rules on the worker side (on each RDD).

Comment: Do you mean a global status at driver level or a local variable at worker level?

Comment: could you add some example code that could help clarify your question?

Comment: @ axlpado thanks for the reply. I mean a variable at worker level.

Comment: @ maasg Sorry for not being clear. I've already update my question.Tks.

Comment: Everything that is being sent to workers (including broadcast) from driver is being serialized there once and is readonly, no cross-executors updates. The way the worker could ask for dynamic state is kind of way to the outside of Spark management system - JDBC, or shared filesystem like Tachyon, etc.

Comment: @ElenaViter Sorry for late reply. Except for Tachyon, how can i achieve this with JDBC,akka or Thread. Can u give me some examples?

Answer (score 2):

The idea here is to write a wrapper over the broadcast variable that gets refreshed periodically. Catch is to call this function inside transform (or any other variation) which allows RDD-RDD operations.

Code Snipped for the BroadcastWrapper class:

```
public class BroadcastWrapper {

private Broadcast<ReferenceData> broadcastVar;
private Date lastUpdatedAt = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

private static BroadcastWrapper obj = new BroadcastWrapper();

private BroadcastWrapper(){}

public static BroadcastWrapper getInstance() {
    return obj;
}

public JavaSparkContext getSparkContext(SparkContext sc) {
   JavaSparkContext jsc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(sc);
   return jsc;
}

public Broadcast<ReferenceData> updateAndGet(SparkContext sparkContext){
    Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    long diff = currentDate.getTime()-lastUpdatedAt.getTime();
    if (var == null || diff > 60000) { //Lets say we want to refresh every 1 min = 60000 ms
        if (var != null)
           var.unpersist();
        lastUpdatedAt = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        //Your logic to refresh
        ReferenceData data = getRefData();

        var = getSparkContext(sparkContext).broadcast(data);
   }
   return var;
 }
}
```

To use this method we can do something like ->

```
objectStream.transform(stream -> {
    Broadcast<ReferenceData> refdataBroadcast = BroadcastWrapper.getInstance().updateAndGet(stream.context());

 /*Your code here*/

});
```

Please see  my answer on another thread for better clarity
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41259333/3166245

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14661368)

Comment: New to answering questions .. Edited the post. Thanks @rajeshujade