# Spark Streaming: make updatable result set available for stream processing logic

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

In a Spark Streaming application there is an external datasource(relational database) that I need to query every 10 minutes and make the results available for my stream processing pipeline.

I don't quite understand what is the right way of doing it.
`Accumulators` are append only (as described in the documentation) but I found this:

```
  /**
   * Set the accumulator's value; only allowed on master
   */
  def setValue(newValue: R) {
    this.value = newValue
  }
```

and `Broadcast variables` are only write-once 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

The scheduling aspect is also not clear to me.

Is there a way to make updated result set available for the stream processing logic?

PS
It seems to be very similar to what I need
[How can I update a broadcast variable in spark streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33372264/how-can-i-update-a-broadcast-variable-in-spark-streaming)

Comment: "I need to query every 10 minutes and make the results available for my stream processing pipeline" What do you mean here? There's a table that's being appended to and you need to read the most recent rows?  A query you need to execute? What other data  sources are in your stream processing pipeline?  More information on what you're trying to accomplish here would help.

Comment: There is actually a service with API on top of the database, so I just query the service and it returns an up-to-date version of the data. I use Kafka direct consumer approach and need to 'enrich' the stream with most up-to-date version but querying the API every time(even if inside `foreachPartition` section) is super expensive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a global variable periodically in Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748528/updating-a-global-variable-periodically-in-spark)

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the save in Java and it is working quite. There is similar answer here [Updating a global variable periodically in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748528/updating-a-global-variable-periodically-in-spark/41261399#41261399) and also mentioned in question

```
public Broadcast<Map<String, List<String>>> updateBroadcastVariable(
  SparkContext sparkContext, DatabaseService databaseService) {
Date d = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
long diff = d.getTime()-mysqlLastUpdatedAt.getTime();
if (updatedVar == null || diff > 60000) {
  if (var != null)
    updatedVar.unpersist();
  mysqlLastUpdatedAt = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
  Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    List<String> dbData = databaseService.refreshData(JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(sparkContext));
  }
  updatedVar = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(sparkContext).broadcast(dbData);
}
return updatedVar;
}
```