# how to refresh broadcast variables

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm using spark-sql-2.4.1v , kafka-client 10.x with java8. 
I need to broadcast some configuration/ meta data information in my spark application.

currently using spark structured streaming , in my application , in every few data my meta-data would change i.e. new records added or current records information is changed.

As it is a streaming application , I only start the application/spark-job once that time I load all these meta-data and broadcast it.

After few days something in meta-data changes how to load and populate those changes on every executor i.e. how to refresh meta-data on each executors?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51980023/647053.  Isn't duplicate of the question?

Comment: yes. try it and see